# Convert to UTF-8 to ANSI and rename files in a folder

Tags: c#, encoding, directory, rename

I want to convert files in one folder to another encoder (ANSI) format and I want to delete the character '.' (for example: 11.12.2016.txt -> 11122016.txt)

I wrote a function for this for single file everything is okay, but I want to make all folder, when I try this its giving to me this process using error.

Here my code - thanks!

```
public void ConvertToANSI()
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryInfo DI = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Ozan-Gaming\Desktop\deneme2");
        FileInfo[] Files = DI.GetFiles("*.txt");

        try
        {
            foreach (FileInfo Fl in Files)
            {
                StreamReader SR = Fl.OpenText();  // this opens a stream to the file **in UTF8 encoding**

                StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(Fl.FullName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate), Encoding.GetEncoding(1250));
                SW.Write(SR.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        // Renaming Starting
        DirectoryInfo DI2 = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Ozan-Gaming\Desktop\deneme2");
        FileInfo[] Files2 = DI2.GetFiles("*.txt");

        foreach (FileInfo f in Files2)
        {
            var charsToRemove = new string[] {"."};
            string fullname = f.FullName;

            foreach (var c in charsToRemove)
            {
                fullname = fullname.Replace(c, string.Empty);
            }

            File.Move(f.FullName, fullname);
        }

        lblSonuc.Text = "OK";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblSonuc.Text = "HATA : "+ex.Message;
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to flush the StreamWriter (SW.Flush())and close the both the streamreader and streamwriter (SW.Close(), SR.Close());

Comment: A StreamWriter has to be closed or disposed.  Use the *using* statement.